# Understanding the proof that a probability distribution is Binomial

Tags: poisson-distribution, proof-explanation, binomial-distribution

This question is driving me insane as the solution to part **(b)** makes no sense, I apologize for having to resort to typing out the question and solution - I don't like having to do this, but in this case I make an exception:

> You are measuring gamma rays from the decay of a radioactive source.
>   The source has a very long half-life so its average rate can be
>   assumed to be constant during your measurements. You place a gamma-ray
>   detector above the source and take data for a day. You calculate you
>   should get an average number $\mu_1$ of gamma rays detected. The
>   probability of actually seeing $n_1$ gamma rays in this detector can
>   be approximated by a Poisson distribution.
>
> **(a)** You also place another gamma-ray detector below the source and calculate this should give you an average number $\mu_2$ per day. What
>   is the combined probability of seeing $n_1$ in the first detector and
>   $n_2$ in the second?
>
> **(b)** Considering both detectors together as one experiment, then for a given value of the total number of gamma rays observed, $N = n_1
>  + n_2$, show that the probability distribution of $n_1$ (or $n_2$) follows a binomial distribution. What is the probability for a single
>   trial for this binomial? Does it make sense?

---

Solution to **(a)**:

Both detectors have a number of hits given by a Poisson distribution, and these are independent. Hence, the combined probability factorises into the product of the two separate probabilities:

$$P(n_1;n_2)=P(n_1;\mu_1)P(n_2;\mu_2)=\cfrac{{\mu_1}^{n_1} e^{-\mu_1}}{n_1!}\cfrac{{\mu_2}^{n_2} e^{-\mu_2}}{n_2!}\tag{1}$$

---

Solution to **(b)**:

Now consider the total number of observations $N=n_1+n_2$ for a given value of $N$,

then $n_2=N-n_1$

Then from $(1)$

$$P(N;n_1)=\cfrac{{\mu_1}^{n_1} e^{-\mu_1}}{n_1!}\cfrac{{\mu_2}^{N-n_1} e^{-\mu_2}}{(N-n_1)!}=\cfrac{{\mu_1}^{n_1} {\mu_2}^{N-n_1}e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}}{n_1!(N-n_1)!}=\cfrac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^N e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}}{N!}\cfrac{N!}{n_1!(N-n_1)!}\cfrac{{\mu_1}^{n_1} {\mu_2}^{N-n_1}}{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^N}$$

$$\implies P(N;n_1)=\color{red}{\cfrac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^N e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}}{N!}}\cfrac{N!}{n_1!(N-n_1)!}\left(\cfrac{\mu_1}{\mu_1+\mu_2}\right)^{n_1}\left(\cfrac{\mu_2}{\mu_1+\mu_2}\right)^{N-n_1}\tag{2}$$

$\color{blue}{\fbox{For fixed $N$ the first term (marked red) is constant}}$. The remaining terms are those of a Binomial distribution of $n_1$ outcomes in $N$ trials.

Recalling the Binomial distribution formula: 
$$B(n;p,N)=\cfrac{N!}{n_1!(N-n_1)!}p^n(1-p)^{N-n}\tag{3}$$
where $p$ here is the outcome for a single trial.

Comparing $(2)$ with $(3)$ $\implies p=\cfrac{\mu_1}{\mu_1+\mu_2}$

so $1-p=1-\cfrac{\mu_1}{\mu_1+\mu_2}=\cfrac{\mu_1 +\mu_2 -\mu_1}{\mu_1+\mu_2}=\cfrac{\mu_2}{\mu_1+\mu_2}$ as required. The average fraction of the events in the upper detector is $\cfrac{\mu_1}{\mu_1+\mu_2} =
p$, so this makes sense.

```
End of proof
```

---

I understand everything in this proof apart from the part marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$. I also completely understand what the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue} \space \mathrm{box}}$ is saying about the $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ term being constant. But the only way the distribution can be Binomial in order to match $(3)$ is: 
$$\color{red}{\underbrace{\cfrac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^N e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}}{N!}}_{=1}}\cfrac{N!}{n_1!(N-n_1)!}\left(\cfrac{\mu_1}{\mu_1+\mu_2}\right)^{n_1}\left(\cfrac{\mu_2}{\mu_1+\mu_2}\right)^{N-n_1}$$

But this can't be the case since $P(N;\mu_1+\mu_2)=\color{red}{\cfrac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^N e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}}{N!}}\ne 1$

Clearly I am missing the point here, so if someone could kindly point it out for me I would be most grateful.

Comment: I will call the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ because I like caps. The presentation is suboptimal. We want the *conditional distribution* of $X_1$ **given** that $X_1+X_2=N$.  Now $X_1+X_2$ is Poisson, parameter $\mu_1+\mu_2$, and the stuff in red is the probability that $X_1+X_2=N$. For the conditional probability we need to **divide** by this.

Comment: It looks to me as if the writer is trying to avoid mention of conditional probability. That is somewhat suprising, since in most probability courses it comes quite early, and is indispensable as a problem-solving tool. Anyway, for fixed $N$ and independent Poisson $X_1$ and $X_2$, the conditional distribution of $X_1$ (or $X_2$), **given** that $X_1+X_2=N$, is binomial   ..

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your reply, probability and distribution theory is not my strong point. I just need to know whether the expression in red is unity?

Comment: It isn't equal to $1$. Actually, you explained yourself in the post why it is not equal to $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That was my belief, not part of the proof, that red factor out the front will scale the binomial distribution, so does that still mean it is binomial?

Comment: A scaled binomial is not only not a binomial, it is not a probability distribution at all, since (if the scaling factor is not $1$!) the "probabilities" don't add up  to $1$.

Comment: To quote you, the number $e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}\frac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^N}{N!}$ cannot be $1$ since it is the prrobability that a Poisson parameter $\mu_1+\mu_2$ is equal to $N$, and that is never $1$. As I wrote earlier, the number is the probabilit that $X_1+X_2=N$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Then I really have no idea, I have simply placed a word for word copy as what was given to me in text. They seem to think if the red term is constant then it's binomial. I disagree.

Comment: I agree that calling the thing binomial is at least very unusual.  This really has little to do with approximating a Poisson by a binomial. A Poisson with parameter $\lambda$ can be thought of as a binomial with large $n$ and $p=\lambda/n$.

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: Not very enlightening: "Error: 401 Forbidden That action is not authorized. Please ensure that you are authenticated."

Comment: OK, thanks. What is the institution?

Comment: Rereading the present page, I feel none of the answers you received so far addresses your question. It seems that the situation is the following: $(X,Y)$ are two integer-valued random variables such that, for every $(i,j)$, $$P(X=i,Y=j)=p(i)q(i,j)$$ for some families of positive real numbers $(p(i))$ and $(q(i,j))$ **Then $p$ is roughly the distribution of $X$ and $q$ is roughly the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditioned on $X$**. More precisely, there exists sone nonzero $c$ such that, for every $i$, $$P(X=i)=\frac1cp(i),$$ and, for every $(i,j)$, $$P(Y=j\mid X=i)=cq(i,j).$$ ...

Comment: ... The value of $c$ is known since $$c=\sum_ip(i).$$ A consequence is that, when, as in your question, $c=1$, $p$ and $q$ are exactly the distribution of $X$ and the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditioned on $X$. Thus, the explanation you are after, is not at all that every red term (that is, $p(i)$ in the abstracted situation of this comment) should be equal to $1$ (they are not) but that their sum over $N$ (that is, $c$ here) is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$  be fixed.  The number $e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}\frac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^N}{N!}$ cannot be $1$ since it is the probability that a Poisson with parameter $\mu_1+\mu_2$ is equal to $N$, and that is never $1$.

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are your two Poisson random variables, then 
$$e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}\frac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^N}{N!}=\Pr(X_1+X_2=N).$$

To find the *conditional distribution* of $X_1$, **given** that $X_1+X_2=N$, divide the expression in your post by the part in red. The conditional distribution of $X_1$ given that $X_1+X_2=N$ is binomial.

**However**, we can think of $N$ as variable also. Then we get a bivariate distribution which gives us the probability that $X_1+X_2=N$ and $X_1=x_1$. This bivariate distribution is not binomial.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite understanding your question, but I will provide my own explanation of this approximation in the hopes that it will help. Let $S_n\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,p_n)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty} np_n = \lambda$. Then the generating functions of $S_n$ and $Y$ are
$$P_n(z) = (1-p_n+p_nz)^n,\quad\quad Q(z) = e^{-\lambda(1-z)}, $$
respectively. In order to prove that $S_n$ converges to $Y$ in distribution, it suffices to show that $P_n$ converges pointwiwse to $Q$ on $(0,1)$. Now, we can write
$$P_n(z) = \left(1 - \frac{np_n(1-z)}n\right)^n=\left(1 - \frac{\lambda_n(1-z)}n\right)^n.$$
where $np_n=\lambda_n$. From L'Hôpital's rule it is clear that
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log(1-t)}t=-1. $$
It follows that
$$n\log\left(1 - \frac{\lambda_n}n\right) = \frac{\log(1-\lambda_n/n)}{\lambda_n/n}\lambda_n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow -\lambda.$$
Exponentiating, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n(z) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \frac{\lambda_n(1-z)}n\right)^n\\
&= e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1-\frac{\lambda_n(1-z)}n \right)}\\
&= e^{-\lambda(1-z)}\\
&= Q(z).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it did hone my intuition a little, but I think there is a simple explanation as to whether the expression marked red equals unity.

Answer (score 1):

Its not enough to do only the substitution $n_1 = N - n_2$. You really need to integrate the second degree of freedom, while minding the proper integration limits and not forgetting the Jacobi determinant.